# Get Vite to load assets from an explicit URL

Tags: reactjs, typescript, flask, vite

I'm experimenting with embedding a Vite app in a Flask app. I'm starting with [flask-vite](https://pypi.org/project/flask-vite/) - and it *is* a start, but has some rough edges.

One of those edges has to do with asset loading from URLs. `flask-vite` runs Vite in a separate server (port 3000), has the developer visit the app through the Flask dev server (port 5000), and expects assets to be fully qualified (ie, `http://localhost:3000/index.css`). I feel like this works reasonably well if you're mostly serving Tailwind builds, but I'm trying to get the TypeScript + React demo working.

With some template tags adjustment, I was able to get pretty far - I can load the demo and it works for the most part. However, the icons aren't loading:

[image: The Vite Typescript + React demo, except the icons are missing]

In the demo, those icons are being loaded like so:

```
import viteLogo from '/vite.svg'
```

and in the app, being used like so:

```
<a href="https://vite.dev" target="_blank">
  <img src={viteLogo} className="logo" alt=Vite logo" />
</a>
```

Vite renders this as looking for the logo at `/assets/react.svg` in dev mode, but in order to make `flask-vite` work, I need it to load from `http://localhost:3000/assets/react.svg`.

Is there a good way to get Vite to do this? Or is my best bet to step back and use Vite's proxy functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Vite does support this! Set the `server.origin` configuration parameter in `vite.config.js` to `http://localhost:3000`. For example, this is my current configuration:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    port: 3000,
    strictPort: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': '/src',
    }
  },
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

This configuration change will fix the icons.